# glob() php function array format

Tags: php, arrays, format, glob

Maybe I missed something, but really, I can't find a solution for this.

I want to change the format of the array I get from a `glob` function.

This is how my code looks now.

```
$my_files = glob('*.php');
```

and the result is an array:

```
array(
    '0' => 'about.php',
    '1' => 'admin-ajax.php',
    '2' => 'admin-footer.php',
    '3' => 'admin-functions.php',
    '4' => 'admin-header.php',
    '5' => 'admin-post.php',
    '6' => 'admin.php',
)
```

**Now this is what exactly I want to have**(*to change the numbers with the text for each array, respectively*):

```
array(
    'about.php'         => 'about.php',
    'admin-ajax.php'    => 'admin-ajax.php',
    'admin-footer.php'  => 'admin-footer.php',
    'admin-functions.php' => 'admin-functions.php',
    'admin-header.php'  => 'admin-header.php',
    'admin-post.php'    => 'admin-post.php',
    'admin.php'         => 'admin.php',
)
```

I need this as an array to include it using a variable in this way:

```
array(
    'name'      => 'Intern download file name',
    'id'        => $prefix .'blog_post_intern_url',
    'type'      => 'select',
    'options'   => $my_files,
),
```

Comment: I still don't understand why it has to be in that format.

Comment: @Jack That looks a bit like wordpress. I assume we do not want to know why this format is required ;)

Comment: @Jack, I have html `select` where are listed all my files from a folder(.zip files uploaded via FTP). And on front-end I have a download button where in the link is this file wich I selected. That's why I need the value to be the name of selected file. And yes, this is a wordpress metabox field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$arrayWithKeysEqualValues = array_combine($my_files, $my_files);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try array_combine

```
$newArray = array_combine($originalArray, $originalArray);
```

Comment: The same answer like @fab . Thank you :)